# How to use GLEW with Code::Blocks

Tags: linker, mingw, codeblocks, glew

This seems to be a fairly common problem that I can't seem to find a *good* solution too. Most forums or questions I've read tell you what's wrong, but don't explain how to fix it very well.  I've bee trying to setup GLEW with Code::Blocks and I've not been able to get it to work for about two weeks now, so there isn't much I haven't tried. I keep hitting linker errors such as:

```
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|57|undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|59|undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|61|undefined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|63|undefined reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|64|undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|72|undefined reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'|
obj\Debug\src\Graphics.o:D:\cold-fusion-engine\ColdFusion\src\Graphics.cpp|77|undefined reference to `_imp____glewDisableVertexAttribArray'|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

How my linker is setup:
[image]

One thing I've read that might be wrong is that GLEW needs to be compiled to glew32.a instead of glew32.lib but I can't get the Makefile to work with Cygwin. I've also noticed this seems to be a some what common problem people have. I know it's a lot to ask but could someone possibly compile GLEW for Mingw and upload it or give a **detailed** step by step on how to do it? I'm having way more trouble with this than I should and it's driving me to the point of giving up on learning OpenGL 4 and just sticking with OpenGL 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I once wanted to test whether a big problem-is to make glew-1.9.0.

I assume you have msys and mingw on the same drive installed. e.g. **C:\msys\1.0\ and C:\mingw***

- downloaded glew-1.9.0.
- set env path, put first inserted into the path variable x:\msys\1.0\bin;x:\mingw\bin;....
- copy folder glew-1.9.0 to x:\msys\1.0\src\glew-1.9.0
- start msys.bat
- cd to top level /
- cd to usr/src/glew-1.9.0
- make

all these steps took about 10 minutes. And in the usr/src/glew-1.9.0/lib folder I can see

libglew32.a .. 15.08.2012
libglew32.dll.a .. 15.08.2012
libglew32mx.a .. 15.08.2012
libglew32mx.dll.a .. 15.08.2012
glew32.dll .. 15.08.2012
glew32mx.dll .. 15.08.2012

So where is the problem ??